# Maximum number of disjoint paths of length k, in a tree- Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming, directed-acyclic-graphs

We are given a rooted tree T and an integer k, and I want to find the largest possible
number of disjoint paths directed towards the root in T, where each path has length k. Do not assume that T is a binary tree. How can I find an optimal solution using dynamic programming? A recursive formula would be really helpful.

Comment: Please define "disjoint path" more clearly.

Comment: disjoint paths are non intersecting, ie they don't have a common vertex nor a common edge. @גלעדברקן